# Can't remove shadow from UINavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, respondstoselector

I can't remove the shadow from my UINavigationBar for some reason on iOS6. Why isn't this working? I've tried the following:

```
if ([[UINavigationBar appearance]respondsToSelector:@selector(setShadowImage:)]){
    [[UINavigationBar appearance]setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
}
```

---

```
if ([[UINavigationBar class]respondsToSelector:@selector(setShadowImage:)]){
    [[UINavigationBar appearance]setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  I would put a breakpoint inside that if to see if it's even called.

Comment: Neither get called, I'm modifying the navigation bar's background by checking if [UINavigationBar class] responds to appearance, and that seems to work just fine. I just can't get it working for setShadowImage. setShadowImage alone works fine.

Comment: Exactly.  If it doesn't respond, and the selector isn't even called, how would you ever expect your changes to be applied?

Comment: That's my question- I'm not sure why it isn't responding to the selector. I posted two different examples I've tried because I'm not sure if I'm just checking wrong object for a response.

Comment: It's possible that the appearance proxy just isn't cutting it.  Try a direct set.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do the work on a NavigationBar instance...

```
if ([navigationBarInstance respondsToSelector:@selector(setShadowImage:)]){
    [navigationBarInstance setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
}
```

Edit: 
If you for some reason really need to perform the check on the *class*. This will work:

```
if ([UINavigationBar instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setShadowImage:)]) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This had me stumped for a while until I read the docs!

NOTE:
For a custom shadow image to be shown, **a custom background image must also be set** with the `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:` method. If the default background image is used, then the default shadow image will be used regardless of the value of this property.

Answer (score 1):

**Mike Pollard** has it right.

To remove the shadow underneath the `UINavigationBar` on iOS 6, you need to set a custom background image in addition to setting the shadow image to a blank `UIImage`.

**CustomViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
}
```

In the above example, "Background" would be a PNG image in your project.